# referring Tomcat JNDI datasource in persistence.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jpa, datasource

in server.xml I've defined global resource (I'm using **Tomcat 6**):

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
   <Resource name="jdbc/myds" auth="Container"
             type="javax.sql.DataSource"
             maxActive="10" maxIdle="3" maxWait="10000"
             username="sa"  password=""
             driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
             url="jdbc:h2:~/.myds/data/db"
   />
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

I see in catalina.out that this is bound, so I suppose it's OK.

In my web app I have the link to the datasource, I'm not sure it's OK:

```
<Context>    
 <ResourceLink global='jdbc/myds' name='jdbc/myds' type="javax.sql.Datasource"/>    
</Context>
```

and in application there is persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="oam" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/myds</non-jta-data-source>
    <!-- class definitions here, nothing else -->

    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

It should be OK, but most probably this or the ResourceLink definition is wrong because I'm getting:

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>   Name jdbc is not bound in this Context

What's wrong and why this does not work?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to get the datasource directly:

```
public class WebAppListener implements ServletContextListener
{
    // ServletContextListener interface - start
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        try
        {
            Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
            Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)
            envCtx.lookup("jdbc/myds");
        }
        catch (NamingException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("!!!! Got NamingException:");
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) { }

}
```

my web.xml:

```
  <listener>
    <display-name>Listener</display-name>
    <listener-class>WebAppListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Still getting the same error although I see the datasource in JMX console when I connect to the Tomcat
(Catalina - Datasource - javax.sql.Datasource = "jdbc/myds" : 
ObjectName = Catalina:type=DataSource,class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/myds". )

Comment: have you resolved your problem? If yes, how?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because of some concept shift there were no further demand.

Answer (score 12):

The `<non-jta-data-source>` in `persistence.xml` should be

`java:comp/env/jdbc/myds`

as per the response in http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1899677

And also is your db driver in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`

Comment: Hmm, can you run through this tutorial and see if all the steps match.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Tomcat_Web_Tutorial

Comment: I'll look at the tutorial although I do not use eclipse.

Comment: The standards do not require that the jta-data-source or non-jta-datasource according to this http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tejb_defjpadatasource.html but some vendors add that support.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make that resource available for the application by declaring it in your `web.xml`?

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>DB Connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/myds</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Comment: This won't work for global resource, I've accindentally turned it on and got datasource with empty properties (class = "", url = null).

But if you have working setup with locally-defined resource, I'm in. I've tried it at the beginning.

Comment: @binary_runner: Didn't pay enough attention, didn't notice the resource was global. And yes, I have a working setup with a locally-defined resource, will post it later (not on this computer).

Comment: Thank you. I'm still not getting what's wrong, everything looks OK but the lookups fail :(.

Comment: @PascalThivent: Have you posted the working setup anywhere? I'm facing with the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(Im using Apache OpenJPA library in Tomcat7 so may not match to Hibernate stuff)

I have never used a global jdbc for my OpenJPA webapps but gave it a try. It worked and this is my configuration. See folder where persistence.xml is saved, probably is openjpa problem but without it nothing works.

**myapp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml**
this is using openjpa provider so class list may not be needed in hibernate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<persistence-unit name="main" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb</non-jta-data-source>

    <class>com.myapp.db.User</class>
    <class>com.myapp.db.Server</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="false" />
        <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported" /> 
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="commons" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrintParameters=true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**tomcat/conf/server.xml**
Add global jdbc resource.

```
  ..cut...
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" readonly="true"  />

    <Resource name="jdbc/mydb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="20" maxWait="10000"
        username="myuser" password="mypwd"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"
        validationQuery="SELECT 1" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
    />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  ..cut...
```

**tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml**
this my development box so I use docBase to link directly to projects folder. You should be find inserting this to war package (META-INF/context.xml) when deployed to production box.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="/projects/myapp/web" reloadable="true" crossContext="true" >

  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
    dataSourceName="jdbc/mydb" localDataSource="false" digest="SHA"
    userTable="user"            userNameCol="username" userCredCol="password"
    userRoleTable="user_role_v" roleNameCol="role" 
  />

  <ResourceLink name="jdbc/mydb" global="jdbc/mydb" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</Context>
```

**myapp/WEB-INF/web.xml**
Add resource-ref to the end of file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0" >

  <description>Webapp</description>
  <display-name>Webapp</display-name>
  ..cut...

  <resource-ref>
    <description>mydb</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/mydb</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

Because Im using OpenJPA+Tomcat7 (not fullsized j2ee container) this may look overengineering but thats how it works. Results are good and developing db-aware webapps is very easy. No need to manual sql query hardcoding and oldskool DAO classes.

Comment: Could you clarify how did you integrate webapp with the openJPA. I have a liferay portlet with openEJB and I'm still getting error
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named kepler_v1PU
I have liferay 6.1 bundled with tomcat 7 and I add openEJB to my project through maven dependency <dependency><groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId><artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId><version>6.0-5</version></dependency>
I can extract it to separate question, but I already find similar on SO.

Comment: I need to post a longer answer later to describe tricks how JPA+OpenJPA+AutomanagedEM is used in pure Tomcat webapp. Key was I found this (now obsolete) helper lib https://code.google.com/p/scoped-entitymanager/  . I modified it to work with JPA2.x interface. It gives an auto-managed JPA entitymanager within servlethttprequest scope. Liferay portlet is an issue I don't know.

Comment: Finally I did this and posted source code, this is JPA2.x compatible wrapper for Tomcat servlet container. Automanage entitymanagers https://github.com/Murmur/ScopedEntityManager